# Trouble implementing UIAlertController. Cant get alert to show up

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, alert, uialertcontroller

I have set an alert to be shown as any error occurs when some user tries to request a new password through firebase, but it is not working.

The `print("problems with email field")` is being printed so I believe I have made something wrong when writing the alert part.

```
@IBAction func recuperarSenha(_ sender: Any) {

    Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: self.loginTextView.text!) { error in
        if error != nil {
            print("problems with email field")

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Couldn't send recover message", message: "Check if e-mail field is properly filled.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: .default, handler: nil))

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to present your alert after creating it. Add the following code after adding action:

```
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Edited version of your code:

```
@IBAction func recuperarSenha(_ sender: Any) {

  Auth.auth().sendPasswordReset(withEmail: self.loginTextView.text!) { error in
    if error != nil {
        print("problems with email field")

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Couldn't send recover message", message: "Check if e-mail field is properly filled.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }
  }
}
```